# Deploy on App Engine via Sublime Text 2 build system

Tags: google-app-engine, sublimetext2

The code below works fine, but in the shell I don't see the deploy log in progress. Only when the deploy is finished appears the log. Any help?

```
{
  "cmd": ["appcfg.py --email=email --oauth2 --passin update", "$project_path"],
  "path": "C:/Program Files/Google/google_appengine",
  "encoding": "latin_1",
  "shell": "true"
}
```

Comment: Sorry for asking it here, but how do you input the password (where)?

Comment: this is an old answer, in the meantime I realized that we can use `--oauth2`

Comment: Could you please post your solution? I've raised separate question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872442/how-to-use-sublimes-text-2-build-functionality-with-google-app-engine

Comment: I don't have a solution because now i prefer a series of bat files

Comment: I'm using "cmd": "deploy.bat" with appcfg.py update . in it, and the workind_dir set to where the .bat is, but that also doesn't display the output until it's done successfully or failed. It looks like ST waits that the command has exited to display its output.