# How to use Sublime's Text 2 build functionality with Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sublimetext2

Two actions I would like to do on Windows 7:

1. update code on the server;
2. validate the code.

In order to do (1) I've created *GAU update.sublime-build* file with the following text:

```
{
    "cmd": ["appcfg.py --oauth2 --insecure --skip_sdk_update_check update", "$project_path"],
    "path": "d:/Work/GAE/",
    "encoding": "cp1251",
    "shell": true
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

> ERROR appcfg.py:2161 An error occurred processing file '': HTTP Error
>   302: Found Unexpected redirect to
>   https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?version=1&app_id=myappid.
>   Aborting.

How to fix it? I've also tried [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569266/deploy-on-app-engine-via-sublime-text-2-build-system#comment17413582_11569266), but it doesn't ask the password.

And I am not sure how to do task (2).

Comment: run the appcfg.py --oauth2 from cmd before (for 30 days don't ask password again)

Comment: I reproduce the some error with `--insecure` flag